# Damaged/Invalid MP4 repair

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a MP4 that was downloaded from YouTube of a High School graduation, video since removed due to copyrighted music//blah blah. Anyways, the video plays with VLC but the audio and video are 2 separate files and when I try to merge I only get a few seconds. Same result when using

```
ffmpeg -i Henrietta\ Bearcats\ Graduation\ 2020.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

ffmpeg reports "Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it" and I *think* that means bad headers.

Any suggestions on how to repair the file, since I am unable to redownload it?

Comment: *he audio and video are 2 separate files and when I try to merge* --> what was the merge command?

Comment: @gyan ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "$invideo" -i "$inaudio" -strict -2 -codec copy "$outputfile";

Answer (score 0):

You have one .mp4 that is audio and one .mp4 that is video, and you want to merge them? I presume you are doing this in VLC:

1. Select Media menu
2. Select Open (advanced) menu item
3. Click Add and pick the video file you want to play
4. Tick the Show More Options tickbox
5. Tick the Play Another Media Synchonously (extra audio file, ...)
6. Click Browse button to pick the audio file you want to play

If that's the case, have you tried out a program called MyMP4BoxGUI? 
https://www.videohelp.com/tools/My-MP4Box-GUI

Comment: I know how to merge them if the file is "valid" the problem is there is evidently either header or container corruption.

Comment: Have you checked these forum posts for concatenating files in ffmpeg?
[Link1]


  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260925/ffmpeg-2-4-2-concatenate-mp4-files

[Link2]


  : https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21315/concatenating-split-media-files-using-concat-protocol

Comment: Again, not trying to concatenate files, I am trying to fix a corrupt/damaged file. You are focusing on the wrong part of the post.

Comment: I'm a little confused then. Which file is corrupted? You say you have a separate video and audio file and they play fine in VLC but when you try to merge them you only get a few seconds of playback out of the output file, along with the error which I do not believe is an error but just a warning. It sounds like you're trying to concatenate the files (join/merge them together) but the output file is acting 'corrupt'.